# Complex function in firestore security rule

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

Let's assume I have a user with public and private key pair (asymmetric cryptography), He sign "data" with his own private key and create a document like this below in Firestore collection:

```
{ "publicKey": "XXX", "data": "XXX", "signature": "XXX" }
```

It is possible to allow create only if the signature is valid using "publicKey" and "data" as parametres using firestore security rules?
or I must use cloud functions to verify and create the document server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security rules language used for Cloud Firestore rules is intentionally not Turing complete.  Also, custom functions in security rules are limited to a single `return` statement with no branches or loops and a maximum call stack depth of 10.  So the short answer is: that's almost definitely not possible.

That said, there are some basic global math functions in rules:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.math

Comment: What is the best practice in this case?

Comment: I would probably use a Cloud Function to perform this verification after each write.